# How to convert tensor output of image segmentation model to image?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-segmentation, fast-ai, image-preprocessing

I am trying the code for image segmentation for self driving cars using Berkley deep drive dataset, I trained the model, and tested an image on it, got an output in tensor format(the segmented image), but I need it in image format, I tried `Image.fromarray` function, got the below output:

[image]

And the actual image is shown below:

[image]

The model I am using is from this [git repo](https://github.com/borisdayma/semantic-segmentation/blob/master/src/train.py).

Answer (score 0):

For tensorflow models I used:

```
from PIL import Image

prediction = np.squeeze(prediction)
r = prediction * 255
im = Image.fromarray(r.astype('uint8'), 'L')
im = im.resize(original.size)
```

Comment: It will work only if the tensors represent the pixel values. However the OPs seems to have got the tensors from a model prediction, which in most cases do not represent the  image pixels and depends on the model output.

Comment: You are right. I missread that. Edit

Comment: @MichalCicatka Thank you, for sharing your solution, but it didn't work in my case, the output I am getting is still a complete black image strip.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the raw output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your tensors are the result of the model prediction and the underlining model is `U-net`. If that is the case, those tensors should represent segmentation masks. If the image used for prediction is of size `512x512` (depends of model architecture) then the predicted tensor size by `U-net` will be `k x 512 x 512` i.e k segmentation masks per image. You have to overlay these masks on the image with lighter colors to see how the predicted image is segmented by the model. So you need access to the image you used for prediction to do this.

Since you are using fast.ai apis I recommend checking the code of `show_results` method of `learner` object to see how they render the output. This should be a good starting point.